# Using Lift charts with multinomial classification model

Tags: multiclass-classification

I’m trying to understand the use of Lift charts with multinomial classification model in the evaluation phase. I can see only one category can be selected to use in ‘x’ axis e.g drugA .

What kind of insight we can get by using a target at a time to create a Lift chart to understand how good is the model?

This is the example I’m trying to understand https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3RA7_sub/modeler_tutorial_ddita/clementine/clemtut_intro_buildingstreams.html